# Open CtrlP on VimEnter Only If Opening a Directory

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I'd like to open `CtrlP` if I am opening a directory with vim, but not a file. I like to have it automatically open in I just open a directory for convenience. However, it is slightly inconvenient if I know exactly which file I want to open because of the added loading time.

Currently I just have this in my `.vimrc`:

`autocmd vimenter * CtrlP`

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to test the args to see if a single directory was passed in and if it was, execute `CtrlP`.  Here is a very rudimentary solution:

```
function! MaybeCtrlP()
    if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0])
        " Uncomment this to remove the Netrw buffer (optional)
        " execute "bdelete"
        execute "CtrlP"
    endif
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * :call MaybeCtrlP()
```

Comment: The other answer was a nice workaround, but this is the answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `.bash_profile`, create an alias:

```
alias vimCtrlP="vim +CtrlP"
```

Then every time you need this, use `vimCtrlP` as you would issue `vim` in shell, followed by the directory.

Comment: Thats a simple solution! Thanks!